# How to extend an interface with object resulting in new interface with object props merged into interface prototype?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

The purpose of this is to have good intellisense on an old code base, which I cannot just turn into ES6 syntax. I have:

```
extend<T, K>(cls: T, xtn: K): T & K
```

---- usage:

```
var NewClass = extend(MyClass /* just a function */, {
  init() {

  }
})
```

I expect the `NewClass` would have `init` in its prototype, but not.

The question is how can I notify Typescript to merge into prototype ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed do this but you need to specify that the type of the value being intersected with the `xtn` object is a constructor that instantiates the resulting values.

The signature of extend therefore should look like

```
function extend<T, K>(cls: new (...args: {}[]) => T, xtn: K): new (...args: {}[]) => T & K;
```

TypeScript will still error if MyClass is not known to be constructable.

We can can overload `extend` to resolve this as follows

```
function extend<T, K>(cls: (...args: {}[]) => T, xtn: K): new (...args: {}[]) => T & K;
function extend<T, K>(cls: new (...args: {}[]) => T, xtn: K): new (...args: {}[]) => T & K;
```

Comment: How do I get the context carried to the new class.  `this.` ? Is it possible ?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Are you talking about static-members or superclass access or something different?

Comment: Edit: I think what i wanted is not possible, since i wanted this to be same this in the result.

Comment: @bigopon can you send me an example? It may well be possible.

Comment: I have put a simple here. [babel repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=extend(MyClass%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20init()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F**%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20This%20is%20expected%20to%20be%20the%20same%20with%20this%20inside%20MyClass%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20Which%20is%20what%20i%20think%20impossible%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%2F%0A%20%20%20%20this.something%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D))

Comment: Is `something` a member of a `MyClass` instance? You can specify what the type of `this` is inside of `init` but there is no way to infer it. So if `MyClass` creates a value that has a `something` property, you can write `init(this: T) { alert(this.something); }`

Comment: I was aiming for crazy dynamic, but it seems not possible yet, like you said there no way to infer it inside the extension props. Thanks for the help with extend though, that's pretty enough :)

Comment: This is now possible with the introduction of mapping type `ThisType`. Just wanna let you know in case

Comment: @bigopon are you just saying it's another way to write it?

Comment: Yes, but it would be not wise to try to explain it here, so here the link https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15836